# How to make API accept URLs as parameters with GET or POST requests using Bottle-python

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, routes, bottle

I am making a simple python API using Bottle. Everything is working fine until I provide the  parameter to be something like `http://sahildua.com/projects/`. Even if I send a URL as a encoded string, it still shows the same error i.e. `404 Not Found`.

```
@route('/expand-url/<url>', method='GET')
def expand(url = ""):
    if url == "":
        return {"success" : False}
```

What do I need to change in `@route` instruction to make it work? Or is there any other way of sending the URL as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the fact that there are forward slashes '/' in the value you are sending to your route. Bottle is interpreting/parsing the API call correctly, just not with you're expecting.
With your current route setup, Bottle is interpreting your API call as sending the value `projects/` to the route `/expand-url/http://sahildua.com/`(which doesn't exist - hence the 404 error), instead of sending the url value `http://sahildua.com/projects/` to the route `/expand-url/<url>` - The forward slashes are mucking things up - so you need a different approach.

I suggest passing the url as a GET parameter instead of accepting it via the route url.

So your API call would look like `curl -XGET http://APIURL/expand-url?url=http://sahildua.com/projects/`.

Then you can retrieve the url in bottle using: `url = request.query.get('url', '')`. i.e.

```
@route('/expand-url', method='GET')
def expand():
    url = request.query.get('url', '')
    if url == "":
        return {"success" : False}
```

This code is not tested but just to give you an idea.

Comment: This seems to settle things up for me. But, giving syntax error on `request`. I will figure that out. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Awesome! I hadn't imported request from Bottle. Thanks, once again! :D

Comment: Ah, yep it needs to be imported.  Your're welcome :).